# Cannot get table caption to be centred

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, captions, apa6

I'm trying to write a table that is

1. not repositioned on the last page. I'm using this

```
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}
```

2. has caption on top

```
\restylefloat{table}
```

3. has caption that is centred.

```
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
```

4. has caption and table number on the same line

```
\captionsetup[table]{format=plain,labelformat=simple,labelsep=space}
```

A snippet of my source looks like this

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man,natbib,donotrepeattitle]{apa6}

\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{isodate}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{format=plain,labelformat=simple,labelsep=space}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{l c c c c c}
    \hline
    Heading 1 & Heading 2 & Heading 3 & Heading 4 & Heading 5 & Heading 6 \\ 
    \hline
    value 1 & value 2 & value 3 & value 4 & value 5 & value 6 \\
    value 1 & value 2 & value 3 & value 4 & value 5 & value 6 \\
    value 1 & value 2 & value 3 & value 4 & value 5 & value 6 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\caption{Some table caption}
\label{table:foobartable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

But my caption is always left justified, I cannot get it to be in the centre. What am I doing wrong? I've also tried `justification=centering` argument in `captionsetup` but it does not help.

EDIT: added full preamble. Sorry, I should've clarified I'm using the `apa6` documentclass not `article`.

Comment: please post full documents not fragments that we can not debug. If I add `\documentclass{article}` to make a document from your fragment, the caption is centred.

Comment: Your code produces [this centred caption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifC9s.png)

Comment: Your MWE produces an undefined macro: `\@shorttitle`

Comment: you could also remove most of the packages not used in the example.  The only reason to use a journal class like apa is so it removes style choice from the authoir and forces the journal style. It is normaly not recommended to change the style at all for such a class. Your question is _only_ about apa6

Answer (score 1):

Your full MWE produces the centered caption on top of the table while using the default mode `jou` (like a printed APA journal) or `doc` (LaTeX document). For `man` will produce the format expected from APA for a submitted article for publication (using double spacing and left align captions, for example).

To avoid compilation errors with the running heads `\title`, `\author` and `\shorttitle` should be defined.

The `apa6` class loads many packages that do not need to be included in its preamble and can cause dependency problems.

**Mode jou**

[image: j]

**Mode doc**

[image: d]

**Mode man**
[image: m]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex    

\documentclass[a4paper,natbib,donotrepeattitle, man]{apa6}

\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{isodate}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\usepackage{float} 
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{format=plain,labelformat=simple,labelsep=space}

\title{Article title to APA} % <<<<<<<<< needed
\author{One author} % <<<<<<<<< needed
\shorttitle{short APA} % <<<<<<<<< needed

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % dummy text

\begin{document}
    

1. \kant[1] 

    \begin{table}[ht]
        \centering
        \caption{Some table caption} % caption on top for APA
        \label{table:foobartable}
        \begin{tabular}{l c c c c c}
            \hline
            Heading 1 & Heading 2 & Heading 3 & Heading 4 & Heading 5 & Heading 6 \\ 
            \hline
            value 1 & value 2 & value 3 & value 4 & value 5 & value 6 \\
            value 1 & value 2 & value 3 & value 4 & value 5 & value 6 \\
            value 1 & value 2 & value 3 & value 4 & value 5 & value 6 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    
\end{document}
```